# Best way for a total noob to create a simple web application

Tags: python, django

I want to make an interactive, simple web application. Where should I start? Preferably python/django because it sounds easiest? you tell me. tia.

Comment: "Preferably python/django "  If you already know this, why not start with the Django tutorial?  Why aren't you doing the tutorial right now?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest is not necessarily the best route for any development work. I would want the most suitable framework for the job with the best learning support and best available tools. Some of the worst coding I have ever seen was done the easiest way.

If you are looking for a powerful framework with good supporting community then you have a range of options. If you are a beginner then maybe start with Ruby on Rails as the convention over configuration methodology would lead you down a path of good practices for a web app. If you simply need dynamic content within html pages then probably look at PHP or ASP.NET, again dependant on your platform and experience.

Which ever route you go, I would recommend a period of intense learning and research before you code anything, otherwise you will look back at the project afterwards with the "I wish I knew that before I started" kind of thoughts in your head. Anyway the best platform is the one you enjoy using, good luck finding it.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by web application and the scope of your project.  More details would help, but with such a general question your going to get a lot of general answers.

For the client side, there's a plethora of javascript toolkits/frameworks to choose from.  Most like jQuery, I like Dojo.  In my opinion, it doesn't really matter which one you choose.  All the popular ones have similar capabilities.  Another alternative is Flash.

Server side, you can do dynamic pages with technologies like jsp or php.  Pure server side, for doing rest calls for AJAX back-ends, you can still use scripting languages like php, any type of cgi scripting, etc.  I build my server-side code with Java/servlets.

But again, with no details of what you're actually trying to do, it's impossible to say what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend PHP since it's one of the quickest and easiest languages. A good way to start would be to look at [w3schools PHP tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Python/Django is a fantastic starting point, with great documentation and tutorials on getting started. If you already know Python, I'd definitely recommend it. If you don't, think about doing a Python tutorial first.